# /var/log/messages showing lots of CE Err=0x2000 even on unused banks (slots)

Tags: memory, centos5, linux-kernel

I recently had to upgrade an old server (HP ML350G5) with used FBDIMM DDR2 RAM (could not get new ones where I live). After rebooting /var/log/messages has been plagued with CE Err=0x2000 errors but system appears to be stable. I'm guessing ECC is taking care of things.

What doesn't make sense is that error logs show the same error on all banks even though I am only using 2 slots (slot 0 and 3).

Installed RAM is compatible 2x4GB Kingstone modules running on Centos 5.5 32 bit. I was waiting for some available downtime to install a PAE kernel to take advantage of the 8GB but I was not expecting the errors.

Other posts suggest on running the a memtest but I wanted to share and see if others have experienced similar errors pointing to unused RAM slots. Could the errors be related to having more RAM installed than what 32bit can take account for (without having a 64 bit or PAE kernel running)?

Error log sample follows.

> Aug 14 21:00:35 umm kernel: EDAC MC0: CE row 0, channel 0, label "": (Branch=0 DRAM-Bank=4 RDWR=Read RAS=12405 CAS=506, CE Err=0x2000 (Correctable Non-Mirrored Demand Data ECC))
>
> Aug 14 21:00:36 umm kernel: EDAC MC0: CE row 0, channel 0, label "": (Branch=0 DRAM-Bank=2 RDWR=Read RAS=3505 CAS=4, CE Err=0x2000 (Correctable Non-Mirrored Demand Data ECC))
>
> Aug 14 21:00:37 umm kernel: EDAC MC0: CE row 0, channel 0, label "": (Branch=0 DRAM-Bank=6 RDWR=Read RAS=12404 CAS=504, CE Err=0x2000 (Correctable Non-Mirrored Demand Data ECC))
>
> ...
> All DRAM-Bank= values appear on the logs (from 0 thru 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have not yet installed the PAE kernel then what kernel are you currently running???

the memtest may not identify the errors due to the memory being ECC memory

try running `edac-util -v`
if there are any uncorrectable issues you will be able to identify the bad memory rows.

Comment: You may need to install `edac-utils` first.

Comment: I'm running the default 32 bit kernel for the CentOS (2.6.18-194.3.1.el5). After installing PAE the OS was able to read all available RAM but the error messages still come up in the log

Here is what edac-util -v returns:

`mc0: csrow0: ch0: 211985 Corrected Errors` and 

`mc0: csrow1: ch0: 129518 Corrected Errors`


Does this confirm bad RAM module?

Comment: It implies that there are physical errors with your modules but I would perform more physical testing on the modules to 100% sure..   Are all modules the same make and brand?   Try removing the rows that are marked as bad and retest.

Answer (score 1):

As per logs, you are getting CE (Corrected Error) messages in the system. Ans you can ignore them, Edit grub.conf and add mce=dont_log_ce to the kernel line which will stop corrected error messages to log in file.

But it always good to run memory check in the system.